# Is possible to get the content of textbox from another class without using a property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, text, textbox

**Hi**, well, I have a problem, and is that I want to get the content of a TextBox from another class using:

```
Dim class As MainWindow = New MainWindow

class.TextBox1.Text 'This will return an empty string
```

So, I searched into Google, and I find a possible solution, and is using a property, but I can use it for 200 diferent controls

Is there another shorter solution?

**Thanks in advance.
Bye.**

Comment: I'm not sure about WPF but in winforms it was possible to set the access modifier on the control you wanted to expose to public(it defaulted to private I believe) and this would allow you to access it how you have outlined.

Comment: You mean this `x:FieldModifier="public"`, I tried it, and it doesn't work....

Comment: does capitilization of the "P" in "Public" matter?(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx)

Comment: I had put it, to saw if it works, and nothing new had happen...

Comment: Maybe set it to a static proeprty?

Comment: How can I do that? I'm new on WPF. :-/

Comment: I read that, and well, I'm not sure if putting this it will work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5080692/3286975